# How to add leading zeros in a month columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, leading-zero

I looked through a lot of other questions but didn't see one that quite fit.

Say I have the dataframe, df:

```
Name     Month
Bob      5
Jim      7
Mary     12
```

I'm trying to write a for loop that would add a leading zero to the months with a single digit (and just print the other months as is), and then I can overwrite the column with the list.

Here's what I have

```
list={}
for i in df['Month']:
      if len(df['Month'][i]) < 2:
          print("{:02}".format(i))
      else:
          print(i)
print(list)
df['Month']=list
```

The code just like this is giving me the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
```

I'm not entirely sure where to troubleshoot that or where to go from here. Thank you!

Comment: You're mixing 2 ways to do loops:
- for i in df['Month'] will evaluate to 5, then 7, then 12.
- probably you meant to do "for i in range(0, len(df['Month']

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use a loop for this (it's for an assignment), so cannot use a workaround with zfill. Thank you trolloldem, I will look into changing that part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go (without loop):

```
df["Month"] = df.Month.map("{:02}".format)
```

Comment: This is much more elegant than loop :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters={'Month': '{:0>2}'.format}).astype('str')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use zfill for this:

```
df['Month'] = df['Month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
print(df)

   Name Month
0   Bob    05
1   Jim    07
2  Mary    12
```